# Client / Server application connection reset Java

Tags: java, networking, client

When ever I run the client after running the server, the server crashes with the error connection reset... here is my code:

initiate a client socket and connect to the server. wait for an input.
Client:

```
    private Socket socket;
private BufferedReader in;
private PrintWriter out;
private String fromServer,fromUser;

public ClientTest() {
    try {
        socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 25565);
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void start() {
    try {
        while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(fromServer);
            out.println("1");
        }
        System.out.println("CLOSING");
        out.close();
        in.close();
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ClientTest();
}
```

initiate a server socket and send a "2" to client and initiate a conversation

Server:

```
    public ServerTest() {
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(25565);
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 4444");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    start();
}

public void start() {

    try {
        PrintWriter out;
        out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine, outputLine;
        // initiate conversation with client
        out.println("2");
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {   
                System.out.println(inputLine);
                out.println("2");
            }
        System.out.println("Stopping");
        out.close();
        in.close();
        clientSocket.close();
        serverSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ServerTest();
}
```

when ever I run the server everything is fine but when I run the client after that the server crashes with connection reset error.

Comment: Can you add your stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClientTest() does not call the start() method. Your client exits immediately after establishing the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Alex's answer is right.

This program also goes to infinite loop. You need to add an exit condition in the while loop of client and server.

Comment: But it crashes instantly saying connection reset I don't think it has anything to do with an infinite loop